# get a single object from an array, according to condition by one of its keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects and I would like to obtain only the object that has the largest quantity, in this example the object with 'id': 4, and trying to use the filter property of javascript, but I have not achieved it, otherwise I can to achieve this?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 80
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "quantity": 30,
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "quantity": 50,
    "price": 230
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "quantity": 100,
    "price": 100
  }
]
```

Comment: @certainPerformance how do you `find` the largest quantity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the right choice:

```
const most = array.reduce((a, b) => a.quantity > b.quantity ? a : b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the array by `quantity`, and then take the first item from the sorted array.

```
var a = [{
    "id": 1,
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 80
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "quantity": 30,
    "price": 170
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "quantity": 50,
    "price": 230
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "quantity": 100,
    "price": 100
}]

a.sort((obj1, obj2)=> obj2.quantity - obj1.quantity)[0]
// {id: 4, quantity: 100, price: 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will map through the array of JSON objects and  keep track of the index of the one with the highest quantity.

```
let indexOfHighest = 1
arrayOfObject.map((obj,index) = {
   if(obj.quantity > arrayOfObject[indexOfHighest].quantity)
   {
     indexOfHighest = index
   }

})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just providing another answer- a bit of overkill using the [math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) library

```
let a = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 80
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "quantity": 30,
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "quantity": 50,
    "price": 230
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "quantity": 100,
    "price": 100
  }
]

let result = a.find(function(item){ return item.quantity ===  Math.max.apply(Math,a.map(function(item){return item.quantity;})); })

console.log(result)
```

This uses the math library to find the largest quantity and then finds the object in the array with that quantity. Not the best answer but a different way of approaching the problem :)